# Google forms to SMS

Tags: forms, google-docs, google-forms

We are using a Google forms to market our mobile app . We are sending a form to our existing users to invite there friends by entering their phone numbers .

what we want to achieve is when they enter the phone number , we need to send an SMS automatically using our SMS gateway API link .

So when they enter their phone numbers and click on submit we want to the below onclick option to be done .

http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=XXXXx&to=+13456787654&user=XXXXXX&password=XXXXX&text= Gana dinero para su clase utilizando UBER para hacer un pago . XXXXXXX

I am not tech , so any other way please recommend .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to use Zapier for the integration between Google docs and Clickatell
https://zapier.com/zapbook/clickatell/